# Add array key value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a network array like the following way

```
"network_contents": [

      {
         "facebook":"contents to all pages",

      },
      {
         "twitter":"twiter contents",

      },
      {
         "linkedin":"linked in contents",

      }
]
```

I would like to add some keys to that array bases on its content. If it is facebook the key should be facebook, if it is twitter key should be twitter. But not sure how to do it.

My requirement is to access network array contents, but it may or may not content these facebook, twitter, linked in values. I need to access its values. When i assign a key value will be easy to fetch its contents. So i tried this way to loop through the array

```
message.network_contents.forEach( function (nwContent) {
                        if(nwContent.twitter) {
                            console.log('nw content', nwContent.twitter);
                        }

                    })
```

can i create an array in this foreach loop like the following way.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "facebook": {
                "facebook": "facebook content"
            },
            "twitter": {
                "twitter": "twitter content"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Your help is much appreciated thanks

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: You seem to be mistaking arrays and dictionaries/objects. `["facebook": {...}]` is not grammatical in JavaScript. You can't simply "add keys" - start from an empty object, iterate over the array and copy items into the new object.

Comment: Try to validate your desired result first, because that's not JSON

Comment: @imkrisna i have edited my question can u please check it

Comment: @Amadan, i have updated my question can u please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of what I said in the comment:

```
var oldsies = stuff.network_contents;
var newsies = stuff.network_contents = {};
oldsies.forEach(function(network) {
  var name = Object.keys(network)[0];
  newsies[name] = network;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave an example of a JS object and not a dictionary and therefore cant add key-values.
You need something like this:

```
    var network_contents = [];
    network_contents["facebook"] = {config1: {name:"config1", value:"value1"}};
    network_contents["twitter"] = {config2: {name:"config2", value:"value2"}};
```

example:
network_contents["facebook"].config1.value; // will return "value1"

You can covert your object to a dictionary easily.